# Complex polynomial division proof

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing

Proof left as an exercise for the reader: For a non-trivial complex polynomial and any given input value $a$, there is a unique integer $k\geq1$ so that $$p(z)-p(a)=(z-a)^kq_k(z), q_k(a)\neq0.$$

My intuition here is to use something similar to proof by induction and Taylor expansion, but I'm not sure if this would be a proof of the exercise.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why wouldn't Taylor *not* be a proof? A polynomial can be so developed around **any** point $\;a\;$ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketch of induction proof.  By the Factor Theorem we have
$$p(z)-p(a)=(z-a)q(z)$$
for some $q(z)$.  If $q(a)\ne0$ we are finished.  If $q(a)=0$ we can use induction, since $q$ has smaller degree than $p$, and we get
$$q(z)=q(z)-q(a)=(z-a)^kr(z)\ ,\qquad r(a)\ne0\ .$$
Substituting back completes the proof.

Will leave you to supply details :)

For uniqueness, if
$$(z-a)^kq_k(z)=(z-a)^lq_l(z)\ ,\quad q_k(a)\ne0\ ,\quad q_l(a)\ne0$$
with $k\ne l$, then we can assume $k>l$, so $z-a$ is a factor of $q_l(z)$.  But this contradicts $q_l(a)\ne0$.

Comment: +1, but I think "recursion" would be the appropriate term here instead of "induction".

Comment: Very nice...and induction is the proper name.+1